# Rewriting "Even the left hand doesn't need to know the tasks of right hand" to "... know the right's tasks"

Tags: sentence-construction, american-english

The base sentence would be:

> Even the left hand doesn't need to know the tasks of right hand

Can I rewrite this sentence, keeping the same gist and being grammatically acceptable, as:

> Even the left hand doesn't need to know the right's task

Comment: The biblical original was *Let not the left hand know what the right hand doeth*, which is hopelessly archaic phrasing today. A reasonable modern version might be *Don't let the left hand know what the right hand does / is doing*, but I don't think either of your versions involving "tasks" would ever be likely to come from a native Anglophone. If you're just asking about the *grammar*, then sure - what you've written is syntactically fine. But if you're asking whether it's idiomatically acceptable, I'd say no way!

Comment: A native Anglophone might say *John is my employee, but he works unsupervised. Even I don't normally need to **know what he's doing***. But I can't imagine anyone using *...don't need to **know his tasks*** there.

Comment: I think it is correct but uncomfortable. I would go for 'There are times when even the left hand does not need to know what the right hand is doing.'